# AJAX form not sending and has no error codes

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is a problem that is really quite frustrating, I was using the iFrame method of sending a form to a hidden iFrame so data can be sent without leaving a page, that all worked but sometimes the form just wouldn't send. This happens from all network locations and is seemingly random.

So I have just changed the code to use the AJAX method of sending a form and exactly the same thing is happening, I can send form after form and about 1 in 20 just don't work.

```
var formElement = document.querySelector("#myform");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "php/upload.html");

request.send(new FormData(formElement));

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
console.log(request.readyState);
console.log(request.status);

};
```

So the code is very simple, for a successful upload all the statuses are reported but when it goes wrong absolutely nothing is logged. I have also put an e-mail notification on the form destination page and this doesn't get sent when the problem occurs. So I know when it goes wrong the page is not called at all.

What would be the best solution here, with no feedback from the AJAX request it is pretty difficult to work with, is the only solution to use a timer a keep checking a connection has been made?

Comment: Maybe your server connection is unstable or similar. Check your Network tab in your developer tools (F12 mostly) for the ajax request and see if it is sent at all. Something like "it randomly works sometimes and sometimes not" doesn't exist in programming.

Comment: There's no way for us to know why it's not working, so there's no way of knowing the "best" solution for it is. You could create a separate timeout functionality such that if `onreadystatechange` doesn't fire in, say, 30 seconds, it tries again. You could even use something like "exponential backoff" (search for it) if you wanted to get fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `onreadystatechange` *before* `send`. Otherwise `readystate` might change before your handler is defined, so it will not detect the event. A successful `send` is likely to take at least a tiny bit of time to complete asynchronously, but a `send` which fails locally might fail synchronously, so you don't see the error.

Comment: That is giving a state of 4 but the status is 0, there are no other states logged before it goes to 4, a good request lists states 2 & 3 as well.

Comment: Your XHR technique fails randomly, just as your hidden iframe technique also failed randomly. Coincidence? *I DON'T THINK SO!*  
Next easy thing to try: Does `send` fail instantly without any network traffic, or does it fail after attempting a connection? Try using Fiddler to see what's happening on the network. An instant failure probably generates no traffic; a later failure will show a ton of useful stuff in the Request and Response; and no failures *at all* means fiddler has "fixed" the problem by massaging the network traffic as a proxy.

Comment: Well I'm guessing it is a network issue it's just odd that it happens so often, do AJAX requests not automatically retry? I have put in a timer to check the status if the upload and then resend the form if it has failed, That seems to have solved the problem.